# Need idea how to implement it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can you give me an idea may be using `javascript`, `jquery` or `angular`

I am generating three random array 
**for eg:**

```
(This values are generating using random array =['member', 'medical', 'rx', 'disability'];)
```

and **output**

```
member      disability  medical     disability

medical     member      disability  rx

disability  disability  medical     member

disability  member      member      disability
```

how do i calculate whether which value is in all column and  maximum occured
for example disability is the answer 
thanks

Comment: Can you give some more details.
so the output is an array of elements from random array..?

Answer (score 1):

In JS you can use JSON to count the number of occurring of a word in your arrays:

```
var countArr = [
    {"word":"member", "occur":0},
    {"word":"disability ", "occur":0}
];

var All = random1.concat(random2).concat(random3);

for(i = 0; i < All.length; i++){
    count(All[i]);
}

function count(word){
    var x = countArr.findIndex(function(elm){ return elm.word == word;});
    if(x != -1){
         ++countArr[x].occur;
    }
    else{
         countArr.push({"word":word, "occur":0});
    }
}
```

and you can easily add more details to your JSON about your word for example the index of occurring a word in your arrays.